# How to change color based on element contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to color `div.rating`. But with values `0.0`, `1.0` or `2.0` etc the div background is always white. Where is the mistake please?

Here is my code:

```
var rating = $(".rating").text();
if("0.0" < rating && rating < "1.6")
{
  $(".rating").css({background: "red", color: "rgb(140,60,60)"});
}
else if("1.7" < rating && rating < "2.4")
{
  $(".rating").css({background: "yellow", color: "rgb(140,140,60)"});
}
else if("2.5" > rating && rating > "5.0")
{
  $(".rating").css({background: "green", color: "rgb(60,140,60)"});
}
else
{
  $(".rating").css({background: "white", color: "rgb(60,60,60)"});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript both these conditions result to true:

```
  "0.0" < "5"; // true;
  "10" < "5"; // true;
```

You have to first convert the rating value to a number. Try this:

```
 var rating = Number($('.rating').text()); // Converting the string into number
 if(Boolean(rating)) // If the text was a valid number
 {
     if ( 0 < rating && rating < 0)
     {
          // Now do what you want to do here.
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

rating is a String, you need to convert that to float. With your current code, it never matches and you get the default case which is white

```
var rating = parseFloat($(".rating").text());
```

Comment: @Gabriel: In addition, compare it to numbers instead of string. I.e. write `0.0` etc instead of `"0.0"`. Otherwise JS has to do unnecessary type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

It's background-color if you are just wanting to set the colour. Not background.

Comment: background is the shorthand for setting everything related to background, one from which is background-color. So, using background to change the background-color of something is valid.

Comment: That is not an answer to the problem... should be a comment (if any).